# CKEditor is ignoring my CSS

Tags: php, html, css, ckeditor

Last time I used CKEditor everything went smoothly. I installed it and it automatically assumed my CSS for HTML rendering. Yesterday I did the very same thing, but this time in another project using zurb foundation as a base for my website. Except this time, CKEditor is just ignoring all the existent CSS...

Here is how I am doing things:

A php file with all the editable fields that the back end picks up:

```
$text13 = "innehall/text13.txt";
if (isset($_POST['body13'])) {
    $newData = nl2br(htmlspecialchars ($_POST['body13']));
    $handle = fopen($text13, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}
if (file_exists($text13)) {

    $myData13 = file_get_contents($text13);
    $myData13 = $myData13;
}
```

The back end file:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post">
    <label>Beskrivning:</label>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="body13" id="body13">
    <?php echo str_replace("<br />","",$myData13); ?>
    </textarea><br>
    <input id="submit" name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Uppdatera fältet" />
</form>
```

A php file with all the sources that the index will pick up:

```
$text13 = "administration/innehall/text13.txt";
if (file_exists($text13)) {
    $myData13 = file_get_contents($text13);
}
```

The index.php:

```
<h2 class="dark_text"><?php echo $myData13 ?></h2>
```

So, the result here is that CKEditor is ignoring my class on my `<h2>`, so my question is: **How do I make CKEditor assume my stylesheet so that the rendered HMTL is exactly the same as I have in my CSS? Or in alternative, how do I make CKEditor not having any styles at all so that the rendering get's decided on my HTML instead?**

Answer (score 0):

## Integrate as Div

You can tell CKEditor to integrate as a div and not as an iframe, that would integrate css a little automatically depending on the cascading dependency in your CSS. See [inline integration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline) and [divArea Addon] at (ckeditor.com/addon/divarea)

## Set CSS and class

Also you can set the body css class and css source file URL(s) to make CKEditor use your CSS.

Check the API [config.contentsCss](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) and [config.bodyClass] at (docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-bodyClass)

Also in your code I can't find any of the required JavaScript to apply CKEditor.

(Cannot post more than two links because of low reputation, you will have to copy the additional links and add the protocol part, sry)

Comment: The only thing I do to integrate CKEditor is having `<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` in the head tag. Automatically all the text areas get converted. As for the rest you said, I will read that documentation and let's see how is it going to work. Thanks so very much!

Comment: There probably is a `CKEDITOR.replaceAll();` call somewhere in your JavaScript code. Or a call to `CKEDITOR.inlineAll();` check doc of CKEditor replacements [here in the API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline). I don't know of the top of my head if this is the default behaviour, but you textareas are being replaced thats good enough, though you should find out which config is applied (most likely a config.js in the ckeditor folder).

Comment: To be honest I already managed to solve that problem with more CSS. Now what is really bothering me is that CKEditor is adding extra <br> to my code every time I press the Enter key. I already tried "CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR" as they have in the manual but this is not working and this time I don't seem to fix the issue with CSS... I don't understand why is this happening now, these issues never happened before when I used CKEditor...

Comment: Find your config.js and the JavaScript code that does the replacement (because you can reconfigure upon replacement). Then probably open a new question and post your config. It's wild guessing otherwise.

Comment: Already did that and didn't work... I have researched a lot about this issue and it seems that it is a bug. Apparently RTE are a hell, a beast to tame and a lot of people have unexpected bugs. I will try to submit a ticket about this, I know I am not the only one having this issue... Cheers! All the best!